# Minus from slider value in AfterEffects

Tags: expression, adobe, numerical, after-effects

I'm making a timer.  When the minutes value reaches 60, it has to decrease by 60 and increment the hour. It's tracking a time lapse; the minutes is currently the time of the computation divided by 6 : each frame is 10 seconds in real life.

This is the code I have so far:

```
effect("Mins")(1)+Math.floor(((time*10)/6))+effect("MinAdd")("Slider"); 
if(effect("Mins")("Slider").value > 60) {effect("Mins")("Slider") -60;}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Comment: Fixed rhetoric and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your setup is there, but usually property values are read by reading the .value property and set through setValue(), so in your case e.g.

```
effect("Mins")("Slider").setValue(effect("Mins")("Slider").value - 60);
```

Personally I'd probably use something more along the lines of:

```
var currentsec = (time*10)/6);
var minute =     Math.floor(currentsec / 60);
var sec =        currentsec % 60;

effect("Mins")("Slider").setValue(minute);
effect("Seconds")("Slider").setValue(sec);
```

though in your case of course for minutes and hours.